# Need help getting wireless drivers to work

Tags: installation

Ok I'm totally new to this, I have Ubuntu installed, my wireless is not working, and I even found the drivers.
So where is the install file?
There are no exe files, and I had to do a whole lot of searching to be told that I must somehow input this information in myself using Control+Alt+T on some command line.

Nothing in this operating system explained this to me.

Ok so I can bring up this weird comand line, I don't even know where the file is located or where it is I am supposed to be sending it to, or just exactly what it is that I the NEW user am supposed to be typing to magically get it there.

What do I need to know to get my computer connect to WiFi?

Comment: It took me 6 months to get the hang of Linux. About the same it took me to get used to Windows 95 ;) Oh and when you have hardware related problems we most times need the specification of you hardware. Have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: With Rinzwind there, I have been using Ubuntu for about 2 months, I am having fun killing the system and rebuilding it so that I can see how things work. If you get stuck, just ask a question and someone will, more often than not, be there to answer it. **Welcome to Ubuntu**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any *.exe file etc.

Open
System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers. You'll see the drivers to install. Just install them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i tried what you said but it does not list the drivers I found, do I need to unpack them or something?

Comment: No. Just select and click button to install.

Answer (score 0):

For most systems, you shouldn't have to use the command line to install wireless drivers, you should only need to do this if your wireless card is not supported or there is some unexpected issue.

As mentioned in another answer, you should be able to go to Open System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers, and there should be the option to install the wireless drivers for your system.

This is the recommended action, however if you're unlucky the option may not be there or it may still not work after you've installed it. If this is the case, then you'll have to resort to installing a driver manually. We can offer help with this though, we just need to have some more specific information, for example what wireless card you are using and what version of Ubuntu you are running.

To find out what wireless card you have (as per [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) instructions):

1. Open up the command line by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `lspci -v` (or `lsusb` if you're using a wireless card connecting via USB). You should get a list of information. Look for entries mentioning 'wireless' - this should tell you the make and model of your wireless card.

Now you're equipped with that knowledge, a quick search via Google or this site will normally provide you with information on installing the appropriate drivers. If you get stuck at this stage (either from lack of information or confusing instructions etc) then I suggest you edit your original question with details of your wireless card, or maybe even delete this question and re-ask a more specific one.